# Q: Multiple If And Statements break when Paste Data

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I need to compile a list of information that pulls from two seperate columns. One column indicates Age (Adult, Kids) the other column indicates gender (M, F) anything that doesn't fall under these will be identified as Unisex.

I've attached my formula below.

This formula was working when I was testing it. I had all genders listed and then manually typed Adult or Kid and got the correct result.

When I move to do a VLOOKUP for Age it will populate everything as Unisex so no longer can it find what I'm looking for.

I'm not sure if there's something wrong with the code or perhaps the formatting of the text after VLOOKUP. I have tried doing the VLOOKUP in a seperate cell and then pasting the values over but still to no avail.

```
=IF(AND(X2="M",Y2="Adult"),"Men",IF(AND(X2="F",Y2="Adult"),"Women",IF(AND(X2="M",Y2="Kids"),"Boys",IF(AND(X2="F",Y2="Kids"),"Girls","Unisex"))))
```

The VLOOKUP I'm using is

```
=VLOOKUP(B:B,'[WPTC.xlsx]Tabel1'!$B:$M,12,0)
```

All it's doing is comparing two prisms against each other and then adding Adult/Kids based on the Prism value.

```
Gender  Age Final
M   Adult    Men
F   Adult    Women
F   Kids     Girls
M   Kids     Boys
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this: `=IF(A2="M",IF(B2="Adult","Men","Boys"),IF(A2="F",IF(B2="Adult","Women","Girls"),"Unisex"))`

Comment: No this doesn't appear to work either. I've been messing with it a bit and it seems as though while the formulas are correct there's something in excel which isn't identifying the text from cell B2 unless manually typed.

Comment: Is that because the return from the vlookup ha a space in it? ('Adult' isn't the same as 'Adult ')

Comment: Hey, I missed this before I saw it myself. Yes that was the issue there were numerous spaces at the end of the text I was pulling thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the source where I was pulling information from had a large number of spaces at the end of each word so it was not being recognised by the IF function.

I've worked around this by adding an additional TRIM formula to an adjacent column and applying this column to the formula.